# Transform a Regex to work in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have the following Regular Expression that works fine but i do not know how can i transform it to work in PHP:

This is the regex:

```
(?s).features::before.*?background: url\('(.*?)'\)
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

Using: `preg_match("/(?s).features::before.*?background: url\('(.*?)'\)/", $DOM, $image_link);`

This is what I get: **.features::before { background: url('http://3dprinting.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Schermafbeelding-2016-05-24-om-15.59.19-1200x500.png')**

and I need only: **http://3dprinting.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Schermafbeelding-2016-05-24-om-15.59.19-1200x500.png**

Comment: It should work in PHP as well

Comment: Use regex delimiters in Php

Comment: @anubhava  I use this: preg_match('(?s).features::before.*?background: url\(\'(.*?)\'\)', $DOM, $image_link);   and nothing detect.

Comment: @anubhava  Ok, I forgot the slash. Well, now it gets the whole sentence. Updating the main question to post the results.

Comment: you need to access the first capturing group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use match reset feature of `PCRE` for your regex:

```
preg_match("/(?s)\\.features::before.*?background: url\\('\\K[^']+/", $DOM, $image_link);
```

`\K` resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lG5gV6/2)